# sub domain redirect to main domain without changing the url not through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I have a site, say `www.xyz.com` and I have a client with their own subdomain, like `www.abc.xyz.com`

I want to be able to redirect users from `www.abc.com` to `www.abc.xyz.com` without changing the url.

I mean, the address bar should show `www.abc.com` but it should connect to `www.abc.xyz.com` or `www.xyz.com`.

I know this is accomplished by editing the `.htaccess` file, but I don't want to go through `.htaccess`, is there any other way to do this? either in a cpanel or other source?

Answer (score 0):

WIthout mod rewrite? I dont really get why you want that but cant you just use include() to bring the desired contents to the current page instance? This would save resources and waiting time for the redirect aswell...

Otherwise you could have a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/de/vhosts/ (virtual hosts) if you are using Apache.

Comment: I have cpanel and can i do from there and i have multiple sub domains means multiple clients

Comment: Sorry, I dont really know "cpanel", is this a webserver management tool? You cannot access the websites code at all? Can you explain in a few word what it does?

Comment: cpanel is the domain hosting service we can say web server of your hosted site

Answer (score 0):

If you're using javascript you can use the History API to achieve this. A tutorial is [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

But basically you would want to run this javascript code after redirecting to www.abc.xyz.com or www.xyz.com. This will update the url in the browser window back to www.abc.com.

```
url = "abc.com.au";
history.pushState(null, "title", url);
```